# Find hidden file via SpotLight

Tags: finder, spotlight

How do I search for a hidden file in macOS?

I know the <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> shows hidden file on Finder, but I am looking for a way to search for it.

For Example, I want to look for `.npmrc` file, and it does not find it in SpotLight nor in Finder Search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to using third party software, you should try [Funter](https://nektony.com/products/funter), which is free. You can search hidden file in an easy way like SpotLight.

> Use Funter to show hidden files, switch hidden files visibility in Finder,
>   hide files, copy, move or remove them.